# new Uint8Array((new ArrayBuffer(64))); と new Uint8Array(64); について

Tags: javascript

**下記に違いはありますか？**
・全く同じことを違う書き方しているだけ？
・それぞれを、使い分ける場面はありますか？

```
new Uint8Array((new ArrayBuffer(64)));

new Uint8Array(64); について
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypedArray のコンストラクタは引数の個数、引数の型によってオーバーロードされています
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-typedarray-constructors

```
new Uint8Array(64)
```

は Uint8Array( length ) というコンストラクタが使われます
length に等しい長さの TypedArray を作成してくれます

```
new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(64))
```

は Uint8Array( buffer [ , byteOffset [ , length ] ] ) というコンストラクタが使われます
buffer の一部を参照する TypedArray を作成することができます

今回の例では byteOffset, length を指定しておらず、Uint8Array の ElementSize は1なので

```
new Uint8Array(64)
new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(64))
```

のどちらでも得られる結果は等しいです

C の union を実現しようとしたり、データ型が切り替わるバイトシーケンスを取り扱う場合(ヘッダ情報のパースなど)、Uint8Array( buffer [ , byteOffset [ , length ] ] ) コンストラクタを利用すると便利です